# Best way to give a file an unique name with php

Tags: php

I was wondering, **without using any kind of user info (id, nickname, age, etc)**, what would be the best way to assure filename uniqueness using php **in a large database with high traffic and most probably simultaneously** between many users? I am using `$file = time()` for example but I would like to know if this should suffice whenever **two users might go over this code at the same time** (at a large large large scale, 10000 users at the same time and the same function ran 200 times simultaneously).

Comment: You can use UNIX timestamp, and maybe a dash of `uniqid()`

Comment: `time()` is not sufficient.  One approach is to use your database to generate a sequence ID atomically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is what I typically use for a random string and then you can append the file type if needed to the end of it

```
sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), TRUE));
```

Answer (score 1):

time is not sufficiently unique, all it takes to get clashes is that line being ran twice in the same second.

This is what [tempnam](https://www.php.net/tempnam) and [tmpfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) are meant for.

Despite the name, you can use tempnam to create files outside of the systems temporary directory, so they will be permanent.

Files created using tmpfile are temporary and are removed at the end of the program at the latest.

Answer (score 1):

Is the file temporary? Then maybe [tempnam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php). Or maybe look at [uniqid](https://www.php.net/uniqid).

Answer (score 0):

Name your files based on the ID that the associated database record has.  Your database guarantees uniqueness of this ID automatically.  There is no need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: 10,000 file creations and DB access/id creations at a time? ouch. Bound to blow something, even crashing the DB. `OP:` *"(at a large large large scale, 10000 users at the same time and the same function ran 200 times simultaneously)"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Folks do this all the time!  He's already got the database in use for this.

Comment: But, 10,000 file creations and ID creations at a time, can it safely be done without crashing DB? Sounds like a rather high number for so little time.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes it certainly can be done.  And yes, it is quite the load.  It's not like you run such databases on a single server.  Sharding and replication are your friends.

Comment: That's what I thought, and on all counts.

Answer (score 0):

Use current timestamp (maybe append microtime) to your file name in addition to the using the db row insert id

Answer (score 0):

Going beyond the context of just naming a file, I use the following call to generate random strings for email confirm hashes etc, but can also be used in your case as well.

```
$random = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(4, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
```

Answer (score -1):

How about **microtime()**? It's like **time()** on steroids.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Answer (score -1):

Use both the timestamp, and the IP address.

Comment: This is no good if you get people behind NAT or a proxy accessing the site at the same time.